# How can I solve a third order nonlinear differential equation (Falkner Skan boundary)?

Tags: differential-equations

```
{f'''[x] + (m + 1)/2 f[x] f''[x] + m (1 - f'[x]^2) == 0, 
 f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, f''[0] == γ}

Beta = 0; m = 0;
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Is this Question about the Software Mathematica? If so please complement your Question with Code. Else [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions) satisfies your needs better.

Comment: Your boundary conditions don't look like the usual ones.  Normally, the third boundary condition is that `f'[Infinity]==1`

Comment: Anyway though, one answer to the question "How can I solve the Falkner Skan equation using Mathematica?" is apparently via [explicit third-order finite difference scheme](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1678-58782011000400001).  This problem is too specialized for this forum, and you haven't really shown what you have tried before, so it will likely be closed.  You should read that paper, and perhaps email the authors for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   eq = {f'''[x] + (m + 1)/2 f[x] f''[x] + m (1 - f'[x]^2) == 0, 
       f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, f''[0] == gamma};
    m = 1;
    gamma = 1;
    sl = NDSolve[eq, f[x], {x, 0, 1}][[1, 1]]

   (*  f[x] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>][x]  *)
```

Draw it:

```
Plot[f[x] /. sl, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: thanks but i need a result :/

Comment: @Imed BouRogaà In Mma the `InterpolatingFunction ` is a result of the numerical solution of a ODE. Check Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/NDSolve